# Spring 4.1.7 @ModelAttribute returning all null values

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring and I am starting a new project.

My Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/loginRequest*" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String loginRequest(@ModelAttribute(value = "loginUser") DepotUser loginUser, BindingResult result, Model model, ModelMap map)
```

My Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#loginForm').attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert('Data: ' + data + '\nStatus: ' + status);
        if(response.status == 'SUCCESS'){
            alert('success');
        }
        //window.location = 'home';
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

My `DepotUser.class` is an annotated hibernate persisted class, and it has username and password fields.

My html form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="loginForm" method="post" modelAttribute="loginUser" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loginRequest">
```

The model attribute returns all the class fields as null.

I have tried form submit `$("#loginForm").submit();` but that does not work either. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Could you put your code in a proper format ? (4 spaces or appropriate symbols around)

Comment: Is the broser sending the form-data to the server?